# Why is my BigQuery retention not lining up with Firebase?

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I found this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/analyzing-custom-retention-cohorts-using-bigquery-and-google-analytics-for-firebase-779777595950) which it mentions how to get retention so it is easier to manipulate, but I can't even get it to line up with just basic retention. I have messed with the dates all I can, but I don't understand why I am still getting anywhere from 2-12% off from Firebase. If you have any thoughts I will take it!

Here is the function:

```
WITH analytics_data AS (
  SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp, event_name, 
    app_info.version AS app_version,   -- This is new!
    UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP("2018-08-01 00:00:00", "-7:00")) AS start_day,
    3600*1000*1000*24*7 AS one_week_micros
  FROM `firebase-public-project.analytics_153293282.events_*`
  WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN '20180731' AND '20180829'
)

SELECT week_0_cohort / week_0_cohort AS week_0_pct,
 week_1_cohort / week_0_cohort AS week_1_pct,
 week_2_cohort / week_0_cohort AS week_2_pct,
 week_3_cohort / week_0_cohort AS week_3_pct
FROM (
  WITH week_3_users AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id
    FROM analytics_data
    WHERE event_timestamp BETWEEN start_day+(3*one_week_micros) AND start_day+(4*one_week_micros)
  ),
  week_2_users AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id
    FROM analytics_data
    WHERE event_timestamp BETWEEN start_day+(2*one_week_micros) AND start_day+(3*one_week_micros)
  ),
  week_1_users AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id
    FROM analytics_data
    WHERE event_timestamp BETWEEN start_day+(1*one_week_micros) AND start_day+(2*one_week_micros)
  ), 
  week_0_users AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id
    FROM analytics_data
    WHERE event_name = 'first_open'
      AND app_version = "2.62"   -- This bit is new, too!
      AND event_timestamp BETWEEN start_day AND start_day+(1*one_week_micros)
  )
  SELECT 
    (SELECT count(*) 
     FROM week_0_users) AS week_0_cohort,
    (SELECT count(*) 
     FROM week_1_users 
     JOIN week_0_users USING (user_pseudo_id)) AS week_1_cohort,
    (SELECT count(*) 
     FROM week_2_users 
     JOIN week_0_users USING (user_pseudo_id)) AS week_2_cohort,
    (SELECT count(*) 
     FROM week_3_users 
     JOIN week_0_users USING (user_pseudo_id)) AS week_3_cohort
)
```

Comment: please provide sample data and show us what you get as output and what you expect.

Comment: For example I am getting Week 0: 1.0, Week 1: 0.518230358504958, Week 2: 0.4951945080091533, Week 3: 0.4631578947368421 VS. Firebase, Week 0: 100%, Week 1: 47.3%, Week 2: 42.3%, Week 3: 37.3%, Week 4: 32.8%